# Got segmentation fault: iogetline.c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

The following code is the problem part:

```
#define NICKLEN 10
...

typedef char * string;
typedef struct donation
{
    string nickname;
    ...
} Item;

...

void eatline(void)
{
  while (getchar()!='\n');
}

...

string s_gets(string st, int n)
{
  string ret_val;
  string find;

  ret_val=fgets(st, n, stdin);
  if (ret_val)
  {
    find=strchr(st, '\n');
    if (find)
      *find='\0';
    else
      eatline();
  }

  return ret_val;
}

...

int main(void)
{
  Item donate;

...

puts("Enter y to start");

while(getchar()=='y')
{
  eatline(); // to remove \n from input
  puts("Enter nickname. Limit is 10 characters.");
  s_gets(donate.nickname, NICKLEN);
...
```

and the following is input, output

```
Enter y to start

y
Enter nickname. Limit is 10 characters.

ffff
```

When I enter nickname, an error occurs(in gdb):

```
iogetline.c: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: Do you ever make `donate.nickname` actually *point* anywhere? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us? And please don't make type-aliases of common types (like your `string` alias), as it makes code generally harder to read and understand.

Comment: Also note that the "error" from GDB is irrelevant, it just says that the standard library source file is unavailable to you, the crash isn't because of an error in the library but because of something you do in your code (or, as I think, *don't* do).

Comment: What is `string` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The member `nickname` in your in your `struct donation` or `Item` is a `char` pointer. So, `donate.nickname` is an uninitialised pointer. It could be pointing anywhere as it is having garbage value.

The value in this pointer is treated as the address of a memory location which may not even be a part of memory that the program is allowed to access.

Upon an illegal access of memory, your program seg faults.

With your `fgets()` in `s_gets()`, you are writing to the memory location pointed to by `donate.nickname`.

You could make your `struct donation` to

```
typedef struct donation
{
    char nickname[11];
    ...
} Item;
```

as the maximum size of the string stored with `nickname` is 10. The extra one character is for the `\0` character.

`fgets()` reads in the trailing `\n` as well. If you want to store that as well, I guess you'll have to modify the size to 12.

Or if you wanted the dynamic memory allocation, add the following line after `Item donate;`

```
donate.nickname = malloc(sizeof(char)*11);
```

and free the memory once you are done using it

```
free(donate.nickname);
```

Comment: thanks a lot! _you are writing to the memory location pointed to by donate.nickname_-I need this explanation!